# Saving powershell command output into a file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I want to save the following powershell command into a `file.ps1` from cmd:

```
powershell send-mailmessage -to "alerts@address.com" -from "info@address.com" -subject "Virus alert" -body "Cryptolocker variant detected on $env:computername " -smtp "companyname-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: The content of your script is malicious, now you may see it otherwise, but what one person may see as a joke or prank  another may not. For that reason I have no interest in helping you with your problem. Your question is also off topic because here we help to fix problematic code, but you have not reported an issue with that code, your only issue is that you've done no research and shown no attempt at tackling the task before asking somebody else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
echo <your_command> > file.ps1
```

`echo` prints whatever you give it (in this case your command) to the standard output (usually the console) and `>` redirects the string (your command) from the standard output to the file `file.ps1`

Answer (score 0):

This can be written to a file by redirecting stdout of the ECHO command.

```
ECHO>file.ps1 powershell send-mailmessage ^
-to "alerts@address.com" ^
-from "info@address.com" ^
-subject "Virus alert" ^
-body "Cryptolocker variant detected on $env:computername " ^
-smtp "companyname-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"
```

If you are writing to a .ps1 file, why do you need to start another instance of PowerShell? To run the PowerShell script, leave the `powershell` command out and just use:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File file.ps1
```

Comment: @SaidNaweed - If an answer works for you, please select the check mark to let others know it was a correct answer. That is the way SO works. Thanks.